# Add button to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you help me solve a little problem?

I have some set of figures. After click, selected figure copied to another div (basket).
In the basket should appear new button. But in my solution this buttom appeared again after each click.
How I can fix this?
Thanks and sorry for my English

This code

```
<div class="products__list__items">
    <div class="products__list__item row">
        <figure class="product first" data-class="first">
            <img src="https://www.tineye.com/images/robot-search-header.png" alt="product1" class="product__img">
            <figcaption class="product__title">One</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="products__list__item row">
        <figure class="product first" data-class="first">
            <img src="https://www.tineye.com/images/robot-search-header.png" alt="product1" class="product__img">
            <figcaption class="product__title">Two</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="products__list__item row">
        <figure class="product first" data-class="first">
            <img src="https://www.tineye.com/images/robot-search-header.png" alt="product1" class="product__img">
            <figcaption class="product__title">Three</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>          
</div>
<div class="basket">

</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var addToBasket = function() {
        var that = $(this);
        if(!that.hasClass('added')) {
            that.clone().appendTo($('.basket'));
            that.addClass('added');
        };  
        $('.basket .product').append('<button>x</button>');
    };
    $(document).on("click",".products__list__item .product",addToBasket);
});
```

Here fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fhxx9hm3/

Comment: Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8rs7zu5x/)

Comment: Do you only want to append the button once? If so, you could use JQuery's `.one()` (It's like `.on()`, but will only execute once per element)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the button only once per product.

```
var addToBasket = function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if(!that.hasClass('added')) {
        //Append the button here
        that.clone().add('<button>x</button>').appendTo($('.basket'));
        //Or
        //that.clone().append('<button>x</button>').appendTo($('.basket'));
        that.addClass('added');
    };  
    //Following statement is not required
    //$('.basket .product').append('<button>x</button>');       
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8rs7zu5x/)

Comment: Thanks!! it helped me a lot!